# Puppeteer Array returns only null

Tags: javascript, null, jestjs, puppeteer

I want to pass all img from the selector into imgs and then push the height from the imgs into an array.

Right now I get an array which returns null for each img.
With plain Js it was no problem but now I try to make it work with puppeteer.

```
await page.waitForSelector(".content-filter.teaser-slider.rondell-section.slides_2 .teaserBorderWrapper .autoTeaserImageWrapper.paddingBottom_twoThird .card-img-top");
   heights = [];

  imgs = await page.$$(".content-filter.teaser-slider.rondell-section.slides_2 .teaserBorderWrapper .autoTeaserImageWrapper.paddingBottom_twoThird .card-img-top");

  for(let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
    heights.push(imgs[i].height);
    }

    await page.evaluate(({heights}) => {
      console.log(heights);
  },{heights});
```

I expect an Array with the height from each img.

I actual get an Array with null from each img.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imgs` won't be an array of DOM elements but Puppeteer ElementHandles. It could be defined as "DOM pointers". That means that the `ElementHandle` won't have a `height` property.

If you want to get the heights you can use `$$eval`.

```js
const heights = await page.$$eval(
    ".content-filter.teaser-slider.rondell-section.slides_2 .teaserBorderWrapper .autoTeaserImageWrapper.paddingBottom_twoThird .card-img-top", 
    imgs => imgs.map(i => i.height));
```

The second argument will be a function expecting the list of images matching that selector. From there you can just simply iterate through them.

You could also split that in two:

```js
const imgs = await page.$$eval(
    ".content-filter.teaser-slider.rondell-section.slides_2 .teaserBorderWrapper .autoTeaserImageWrapper.paddingBottom_twoThird .card-img-top");
const heights = page.eval(imgs => imgs.map(i => i.height), imgs);
```